# Examples of Second Isomorphism Theorem for Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I was wondering if there were any standard insightful applications of the second isomorphism for groups:

THM: Let $ G $ be a group with $ H, N $ as subgroups and $ N $ normal in $G$. Then $ H \cap N $ is normal in $ H $ and $ \frac{HN}{N} \cong \frac{H}{H\cap N} $.

I have read through some helpful posts on the intuition of the theorem and feel that I grasp it now, but am still having trouble concocting a clear example. Any solid examples would be appreciated.

Comment: I have one: find all subgroups of the dihedral group of order $2n$.

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean. The dihedral group has order $ 2n $, so a subgroup with the same order would just be the whole group itself.

Comment: I'm stating that the dihedral group has order $2n$, not the subgroups.

Comment: How does that relate to the second isomorphism theorem? I still don't see your point. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Why don't you work out how to find all such subgroups first?  Say, $G$ is the dihedral group.  $H$ is an arbitrary subgroup of $G$, and $N$ is a "good" normal subgroup of $G$.  How do we classify all $H$?

Comment: Ah, I misinterpreted your initial comments. I thought you were proposing that I find all subgroups of $ D_n $ that have order $ 2n$.

Answer (score 1):

actually there are a lot of examples, sometimes working with $\frac{H}{H\cap N}$ doesn't give the answer so you'll be obliged to use the 2nd thm of isomorphism.
i'll give you an exmple 
whene you want to prove that a sub group of a solvable group is also solvable you'll take your quotients as $\frac{H}{H\cap G_{i}}$  where $G_{i}$  are the termes of the abelian serie of G